# Overleaf Moodle not accepting \$ dollar sign

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to compile my LaTeX with `\usepackage{moodle}` on Overleaf.

Whenever I want to include the dollar sign `\$`, it won't compile correctly.

What's the correct way to include a dollar sign in the document so that LaTeX will compile correctly?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{moodle}
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{test}
\begin{multi}{Word Problem}
A store charges $\$ 1$ for packaging an item. Alice wants to package 10 items. How much does she need to pay the store for packaging the 10 items separately.
\item $5$
\item $6$
\item $8$
\item* $10$
\end{multi}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}`
```

With `\$` in front of "1" it will compile with an error. If you remove `\$` everything is fine.

To be precise, here are the error messages:

```
Compile Error. Sorry, your LaTeX code couldn't compile for some reason. 
Please check the errors below for details, or view the raw log.
nnn.tex

Runaway argument?

for packaging an item. Alice wants to package 10 items. How much doe\ETC.
! File ended while scanning use of \htmlize@inlinemathshift@replace.
<inserted text> 
            \par 
<*> nnn.tex
       
I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
to read past where you wanted me to stop.
I'll try to recover; but if the error is serious,
you'd better type `E' or `X' now and fix your file.

nnn.tex
Emergency stop.

<*> nnn.tex
       
*** (job aborted, no legal \end found)


 Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 3655 strings out of 480906
 62407 string characters out of 5908280
 315048 words of memory out of 5000000
 19216 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 538169 words of font info for 42 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 50i,6n,56p,849b,376s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
 !  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

Comment: Without seeing the code that gives rise to the error messages, it's not easy to tell what's going on. I'm surmising that there are at least two errors in the code. Regarding the first possible error, please edit your posting to show the paragraph before and after "What was the final price?". For the second error, please verify that an `\end{multi}` directive isn't missing around input line 270 to 280.

Comment: Hi @Kevin L, you should have a look to https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that and get into the habit of preparing MWEs for your questions here. You'll learn a lot by doing it and often it will help you find the error...

Comment: you showed an error in a non standard `quiz` enviornment on some internal command `\@htmlize@stop`  but you have given no indication of how those commands are defined nor the use in your document that has the error.

Comment: `moodle` recognizes just a few commands. The text seems to pass through if I use `\$\(1\)`

Comment: @egre Thanks. It solved the problem.  Moodle just doesn't like the regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

The `moodle` package has to perform conversion of TeX material to HTML. In particular, it attempts to grab the contents of inline math environments (`$...$`). When finding the left delimiter (first `$`), the strategy adopted by the package (as of version 0.5) is to blindly look for the next dollar sign. While this works in most cases, your example shows that the `\$` character used in such environments fools `moodle`.

There are (at least) two workarounds to this problem:

1. If possible, avoid the use of the dollar sign inside inline math environments (see @egreg's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/576426/overleaf-moodle-not-accepting-dollar-sign#comment1451580_576426)). The package `moodle` will not be fooled by `\$$1$`.
2. Use LaTeX's inline math delimiters `\(...\)`. The package `moodle` will not be fooled by `\(\$1\)`.

If none of these workarounds is an option, you can fix `moodle`'s internal commands by adding the following code to your preamble.

```latex
\makeatletter
\long\def\htmlize@inlinemath@recursive@i#1#2#3\htmlize@rdelim@i{%
  \def\test@i{#1}%
  \ifx\test@i\@otherbackslash
    \g@addto@macro\mathtext{#1#2}%
    \def\htmlize@next@i{\xa\htmlize@inlinemath@recursive@i#3\htmlize@rdelim@i}%
  \else
    \ifx\test@i\@otherdollar
      \let\htmlize@next@i=\relax
      \g@addto@macro\aftertext{#2#3}%
    \else
      \g@addto@macro\mathtext{#1}%
      \def\htmlize@next@i{\xa\htmlize@inlinemath@recursive@i#2#3\htmlize@rdelim@i}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \htmlize@next@i
}
{\catcode`\$=12\relax%
  \gdef\htmlize@inlinemathshift@replace#1#2\htmlize@rdelim@iii{%
    \xa\g@addto@macro\xa\htmlize@output\xa{\inlinemathleftdelim}%
        \advancemathmodecounter{1}%
        \gdef\mathtext{}%
        \gdef\aftertext{}%
        \htmlize@inlinemath@recursive@i#2\htmlize@rdelim@i%
        \xdef\htmlize@remaining@text{\expandonce\mathtext%
                                     \otherbackslash inlinemathrightdelim{}%
                                     \expandonce\aftertext}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother
```

Basically, the recursive command `\htmlize@inlinemath@recursive@i` ends when the dollar sign is encountered. The point is that it processes together `\` and whatever symbol comes after. Therefore, it will not end when `\$` is encountered.